# Modal is not being presented

Tags: react-native

I've created a small application where you have a button ontop of a `<FlatList />` and setting the onPress to change a `useState()` variable. But somehow my **Modal** is not being presented.

```
export default function Home({navigation}){
  const [data, setData] = useState([
    { title: "1.5 liters Coca-Cola", store: "N/A", price: "20kr", img: "", key: "1" },
    { title: "Gurka", store: "ICA", price: "10kr", img: "", key: "2" },
    { title: "0.5l gräddfil", store: "N/A", price: "12kr", img: "", key: "3" },
  ])

  const [modalOpen, setModalOpen] = useState(false)
    
  return(

    <View style={styles.container}>

      <FlatList 
        data={data}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <ListCard>
            <View style={styles.firstCol}>
              <Text style={styles.listText}>{ item.title }</Text>
              <Text>Price: { item.price }</Text>
            </View>
            <Text>Store: { item.store }</Text>
            <Text>{ item.img }</Text>
          </ListCard>
        )}
      />

      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.addNewButton} onPress={() => setModalOpen(true)}>
        <Text style={styles.addNewButtonText}>+</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <Modal visible={modalOpen} animationType="slide">
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text>Hadedsadasdasasd</Text>
        </View>
      </Modal>

    </View>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container:{
    flex: 1,
  },
  firstCol:{
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
  },
  listText: {
    fontSize: 20
  },
  addNewButton:{
    width: 75,
    height: 75,
    backgroundColor: "blue",
    borderRadius: 37.5,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    alignSelf: "flex-end",
    marginRight: 15,
    marginBottom: 15,
    position: "relative",
    bottom: 0,
    right: 0
  },
  addNewButtonText:{
    fontSize: 50,
    textAlign: "center",
    color: "white"
  }
})
```

I've tried to:

1. Replace **setModalOpen(true)** to **console.log("text")** and the button does print.
2. I've tried to put the **Button** and **Modal** above the Flatlist.
3. When I set `<Modal visible={true}` it does opens when the app is starting.

So is there any way I can open the Modal using this `<TouchableOpacity>`? If yes, how can I do this?

Do I have to reload the modal somehow after the variable is changed?

---

EDIT

After investigating this even more the problem seems to appear when I'm using a "MaterialBottomTabBar". Is there any way around this issue? If not, example how I can do this any different?

Comment: I am unable to find the reason why its not rendering. What is the Modal imported from ? 
Also to your question if you need to reload the modal after the variable is changed - You do not. Once the state is changed, in this case `modalOpen`, the component will rerender with new state.

Comment: @shad0wec
Modal is imported from 'react-native' like this:
`import { StyleSheet, View, Text, FlatList, TouchableOpacity, Modal, Button } from 'react-native'`

Yeah, even tho I log the "modalOpen" it does print "true" when I tap the button. And if I place a console.log('') inside the <Modal> it's getting printed. But somehow its not being visible. Maybe there's an issue with the styling?

Comment: Well, you said that it is visible when you set `visible={true}`, so I would not say that styles are the problem. Anyway, I think that `Modal` should not be inside of the `View`. But I do not think that its going to solve the problem.

Comment: @shad0wec It is required to put the modal inside a view :/